MacOS Sequoia keyboard shortcut to move a window between different screens
I have three screens on my computer but I only use one of them when I am sharing my screen in a meeting, I want a quick keyboard shortcut to move the window to the screen I am using to share.
I used the keyboard shortcuts for an app but that didn't work either.

You must make sure you are using a shortcut that is not already in use.
E.g., you cannot use ^ + ->

Thank you, Luis. That was the issue, I was following the correct steps but apparently, I was using a shortcut that was already used for another shortcut.
